# Compare the strings with special characetr at end

Tags: python, string, comparison

I have two sets

```
a[i]={'aaa@','bb','ccc@'}
b[j]={'aaa','bb@','ccc@'}
```

I want to compare each string in `a[i]` with `b[j]` such that if both strings are same and they have special character at end then it prints "equal" like `ccc@` in above lists are same if strings are equal but one of them have a special character then it displays "Not completely matched"

Comment: You have *sets*, not lists.

Comment: yes so how to compare using sets

Comment: @abd, could you specify what string do you want to compare with what other string? You see, it is a problem that you have sets instead of lists, because sets are not ordered and there is no way to tell, which element of the first set you want to compare to which element of the second set.

Comment: I want to compare all elements of first set with all elements of other set

Comment: I have strings which are words like first set {"Product invoice","product verification","product completed@"} and second set {"Product invoice","product verification@","product completed@"}

Answer (score 1):

an exampel with list:

```
a=['aaa@','bb','ccc@']
b=['aaa','bb@','ccc@']

index = 0
print "ordered comparison:"
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    if i == j:
        print str(index) + ": Equal"
    elif i.replace("@","") == j.replace("@",""):
        print str(index) + ": Not completely Matched"
    else:
        print str(index) + ": Different"
    index+=1

print "\nunordered comparison:"
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        if x == y:
            print x,y + " are Equal"
        elif x.replace("@","") == y.replace("@",""):
            print x,y + " Not completely Matched"
        else:
            print x,y + " Different"
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But the OP is using *sets*, which have no order and cannot just be zipped together. Also, where does it say in the question that the elements can be paired up so neatly?

Comment: The questin says list, and the usage a[i] and b[j] shows mathematical notation. The question was side lined when someone commented about sets. I had already tried this solution by then.

Comment: That someone was me; the OP has confirmed they have sets.

Comment: Also, the OP has added: *I want to compare all elements of first set with all elements of other set*.

Comment: no, he asked if he could see an example with set atleast.

Comment: When we speak we sometimes tend to use set in place of list. This is what made me continue to use this example.

Comment: let me see if i can quickly check this with set as well :)

Comment: I want all comparisons by using zip it compare index wise in above example i want total nine comparisons not three

Answer (score 0):

[Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) are easily compared element by element:

```
>>> a={'aaa@','bb','ccc@'}
>>> b={'aaa','bb@','ccc@'}
>>> c=a.copy()
>>> a-b
set(['aaa@', 'bb'])
>>> a-c
set([])

>>> d={"Product invoice","product verification","product completed@"}
>>> e= {"Product invoice","product verification@","product completed@"}
>>> d-e
set(['product verification'])
>>> d^e
set(['product verification@', 'product verification'])
```

Then use the [truthiness](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of an empty or non empty set to get what you want:

```
>>> 'not matched' if a-b else 'matched'
'not matched'
>>> 'not matched' if a-c else 'matched'
'matched'
```